# character reassignment in 2d matrix throws segmentation fault

Tags: c

Dynamic memory allocation professional corp. reporting in. This time we're in two dimensions, which is certainly harder than one. I can't seem to make an assignment to a dynamically allocated array without throwing a segfault:

```
void some_func(char ** some_grid)
{
    some_grid[0][0] = '0'; // ERROR!
}

int main()
{
    ...

    char **some_grid = malloc(gridSize * sizeof(char *));
    for(int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        some_grid[i] = malloc(gridColSize * sizeof(char));
    }
    some_grid[0] = "11010";
    some_grid[1] = "11001";
    some_grid[2] = "00100";
    some_grid[3] = "01011";

    some_func(some_grid);
}
```

If the problem isn't visible, I can provide more code.

Comment: Where is `gridSize ` given a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`some_grid[0] = "11010";`, etc. assigns a pointer to an immutable *String-Literal* to the address of `some_grid[0]` overwriting the pointer allocated by `malloc` resulting in a memory leak. Your attempt to modify the content in `some_func()` attempts to modify read-only memory resulting in a SegFault.

Instead of `some_grid[0] = "11010";` you want

```
strcpy (some_grid[0], "11010");
```

This presumes that `gridColSize >= 6`. `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` so it should be omitted in:

```
some_grid[i] = malloc(gridColSize);
```

Additionally, you must validate every allocation, e.g.

```
if (!(some_grid[i] = malloc(gridColSize))) {
    perror ("malloc-some_grid[i]");
    return 1;                             /* or handle the error as wanted */
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. You were headed in the right direction, you just ran into the string literal issue. The rest are just suggested improvements `:)`